# VB.NET Split Text File In Parts

Tags: vb.net, string, loops, text, split

Let's say a text file contains:

```
<-NewItems->
Alpha
Omega
Beta
<-NewItems->
Delta
Gamma
Epsilon
<-NewItems->
Something
Something
```

And I want to make a new text file with the items every time `<-NewItems->` is found. I am thinking its more of a For-Each or Do-while method but I can't figure out how to code it. I'm new to visual basic.

Edit: Will someone tell me how or at least lead me where I can figure it out myself?

Thank you.

Comment: So, what is the question? are you asking if it's better to use a for each loop or a do while loop?

Comment: try searching: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yw67h925.aspx

Comment: @ZoharPeled Edited. ^

Comment: You should try this with a filestream and read a line on each loop. One hint: While not streamreader.eof

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Private Sub Example()
    Dim counter As Integer = 1
    Dim input As String = @"
        <-NewItems->
        Alpha
        Omega
        Beta
        <-NewItems->
        Delta
        Gamma
        Epsilon
        <-NewItems->
        Something
        Something"

    For Each content In input.Split({"<-NewItems->"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText($"somefolder/myfile{counter}.txt", content, True)
        counter += 1
    Next
End Sub
```